# C# WebSocket Server

Tags: c#, сокет, websocket

Как создать вебсокет сервер, чтобы к нему могли подключиться не только локально, но и пользователи по всему миру?

Код на данный момент:

```html
private static WebSocketServer wsServer;
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            wsServer = new WebSocketServer();
            int port = 8088;
            wsServer.Setup(port);
            wsServer.NewSessionConnected += WsServer_NewSessionConnected;
            wsServer.NewMessageReceived += WsServer_NewMessageReceived;
            wsServer.NewDataReceived += WsServer_NewDataReceived;
            wsServer.SessionClosed += WsServer_SessionClosed;
            wsServer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server is running on port " + port + ". Press ENTER to exit....");
            Console.ReadKey();


            

        }
        private static void WsServer_SessionClosed(WebSocketSession session, SuperSocket.SocketBase.CloseReason value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SessionClosed");
        }

        private static void WsServer_NewDataReceived(WebSocketSession session, byte[] value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NewDataReceived");
        }

        private static void WsServer_NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NewMessageReceived: " + value);
            if (value == "Hello server")
            {
                session.Send("Hello client");
            }
        }

        private static void WsServer_NewSessionConnected(WebSocketSession session)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NewSessionConnected");
        }
```

Comment: Смысл сервера, к которому можно подключиться только локально?

Comment: Ну так, требуется сделать наоборот, чтобы могли подключиться не локально)
Этого я и не знаю как сделать. Есть Windows server 19, где планирую его поставить. Но реализацию чтобы могли подключаться не локально, не могу сделать.

Comment: Что значит `не могу`? В предлагаете гадать что вы за сервер ставите, как вы его запускаете, как вы его конфигурируете, какие проблемы получаете? Вы же не написали ничего в своем вопросе.

Comment: Извиняюсь, изменил тему.

Comment: А проблема случаем не в закрытых портах? :3

Comment: Порт открыт, только что проверил, но с клиента не подключается, просто вечное ожидание.

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/4TKGnfe8RR_0H6K2BLYUoQ.png

Comment: порт-то пробросили?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? @trollingchar

Comment: Если вы соединяетесь через роутер, то из интернета виден айпи роутера и подключения на порт вашего сервера не доходят, пока вы его не пробросите. Посмотрите как настроить проброс портов для вашей модели роутера (на английском это port forwarding).

Comment: Такая ситуация, что я использую windows server 2019 от гугл, как это можно реализовать на нем?

Comment: Пробросил вроде бы все, порт прослушивается.
http://prntscr.com/p0x4a4
Но проблема такая же, бесконечное подключение к вебсерверу

Хотя моя основная машина подключилась судя по мониторингу http://prntscr.com/p0x5av

Comment: Ситуация изменилась, подключение идет секунд 30, вебсокет сервер закрывает сессию, и возвращается пустой ответ клиенту...

Comment: Ну так что, поможете?